# Use base component for dynamically create component

Tags: angular

I'm currently building a dashboard with multiple dashlet components who all share the same inputs. All inputs are defined in a base component. What I'd like to do in my dashboard component is to dynamically create all dashlets with ngFor and use the base component as a sort of placeholder which will be replaced by a child component.

I'm looking for a solution where I can use Input and Output decorators because it makes the code more maintainable. It makes the whole story with ChangeDetection simpler and I can use things like ngOnChanges. So ComponentFactory isn't a solution I'm looking for though it technically works.

Here's an example of what I'm thinking about:

base.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-base',
  templateUrl: './base.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./base.component.scss']
})
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() id: number;
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

child.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    // do something on changes
  }
}
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let dashlet of dashletList">
  <app-base [id]="dashlet.id" [name]="dashlet.name" *ngComponentOutlet="dashlet"></app-base>
  <!-- later app-base withh be replaced by app-child or any other dashlet-->
</div>
```

Comment: what do child components differ from base component? that might affect the actual  implementation.

Comment: @ABOS child component implements all charts later needed for the dashboard. This can in some cases be some complex ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-content` in BaseComponent, so that you can put all common pieces in BaseComponent, but all distince pieces from child components under `ng-content`. And in AppComponent, change it accordingly,

```
<div *ngFor="let dashlet of dashletList">
  <app-base [id]="dashlet.id" [name]="dashlet.name">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="dashlet.type"></ng-container>
  </app-base>
  <!-- later app-base withh be replaced by app-child or any other dashlet-->
</div>
```

demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppscqy